# Linearly independency of column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be row equivalent matrices. Prove the following statements.

(a) A given set of columns of $A$ is linearly independent if and only if the set of corresponding columns of $B$ is linearly independent.

(b) A given set of columns of $A$ forms a basis for the column space of $A$ if and only if the set of corresponding columns of $B$ forms a basis for the column space of $B$.

Comment: What do you mean with “equivalent matrices”? Maybe “similar”?

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

(a) I believe you mean Matrix **A** and **B** are row equivalent (m×n) matrices, and **B** is in reduced echelon form. Now suppose, the colum vectors of $v_1$ to $v_n$ of B are linearly independent. Then, by definition ¬∃$v_k$ ∀k∈(1,n) such that it can be written as $v_1$+$v_2$+...$v_n$=$v_k$. Therefore, vector colums of Matrix **A** are linearly independent since **A** and **B** are row equivalent. 
This is just one direction of conditional. You can show the other direction holds too.

(b)  Start by writing out what it means to be a basis for a subspace, from there use the proof for part (a) and show that the column vectors of **B** form a basis for **A**.
**Hint**: You will use linear independence.